# strategy.entry() is not opening a position when it should

Tags: pine-script

I am very new to Pine Script and I'm experimenting with my first strategy. I thought I had it working, but then I noticed a single historical bar, on a single ticker, on a single time frame, where the call to `strategy.entry(...)` is not opening a position, while working correctly in all other cases that I scrutinised. I am hoping to get some assistance with figuring out what's going on, as I am out of ideas.

Here's the code that is responsible for opening and closing my position:

```
//@version=4
strategy('My Strategy', 
     overlay = false, 
     max_labels_count=500, 
     calc_on_every_tick=true, 
     initial_capital=10000, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100,
     commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.1)

var debugLong = array.new_int(1) // Using an array to enable setting of global variable from function
bgcolor(array.get(debugLong, 0) ? color.yellow : na)

go_long() =>
    if ( strategy.position_size <= 0 )
        array.set(debugLong, 0, 1) // Make background yellow
        strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)

close_long() =>
    array.set(debugLong, 0, 0) // Turn off background highlight
    strategy.close("long")
```

So the code above is set up to start painting my background yellow when we open a position, and then stop the paint when we exit. This way I can look at my strategy pane and easily correlate the yellow segments with the position markers.

And this is what I see:
[image]

So, the last yellow segment is missing the corresponding open of position... I know that `strategy.entry(...)` has been executed, b/c the yellow background segment is there, but why is there no position marker, like there is for all the other yellow segments? When I look at the list of trades, my position is not in that list either.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's hard to know for sure without the entire code to test on, but I would be more suspect of the debugging method than the condition triggering a color change, but not triggering an entry. Maybe try getting rid of those functions and not using an array as a workaround. If you want the functions have them return true or false and test based on that. Also you don't need parenthesis for the if statement,

Answer (score 0):

I have a fix.

It seems that the behaviour I observed is what happens when `strategy.entry(...)` is **called more than once** in the same calculation round.

I had an if-statement for various entry conditions, each calling my `go_long()` function when satisfied. The problematic bar happened to satisfy more than one of my entry conditions, so `go_long()` got called twice. Somehow, calling my function twice results in no position, even though I had the `if ( strategy.position_size <= 0 )` line in there... I would have thought that the first call would open the position, and the second call would trigger the if-statement, but that's clearly not what is actually happening. So maybe a bug in the language?

In any case, my problem is solved by changing my if-statement into if-else-statement to ensure that only a single call to `go_long()` is possible. Now everything works as expected.